# git - stash and add don't see any changes but checkout does and fails

Tags: git, git-stash, git-checkout

I have a very weird case for y'all.

git can't add my changes, complaining that no changes exist. But a checkout fails since git does see local changes that would be overwritten.

```
modify tracked file foo.sh in topic branch

$git add -p foo.sh
No changes.

$git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        foo.sh
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

$git stash
No local changes to save
```

(file and branch names changed for clarity)

I don't have any gitignore files. My repository resides on a network mounted volume. Could this be an issue?

Comment: What does `git status` say? Do you have an odd configuration of `core.eol`, `core.safecrlf`, or `core.autocrlf`? Do you have any smudge/clean filters defined or other `.gitattributes` hackery going on?

Comment: I have set `core.ignoreStat true`. But I was under the impression that `git add` shouldn't have a problem with that.

Comment: I think you'll need to review the `ignoreStat` discussion in `git help config` and then the section under 'USING "ASSUME UNCHANGED" BIT' in `git help update-index`. With `ignoreStat` set, there are a few other steps you need to take for `git` to notice various types of changes...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the relevant help files. That allowed me to solve the issue.